# How to implement Bootstrap 4 in WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I saw some theme in WordPress which is created using Bootstrap 4 framework.

Bootstrap 4 requires jQuery v 3.2.1.

Currently, WordPress core jQuery version is v 1.12.4. They're using old jQuery version to support old themes and plugins which is coded in jQuery v. 1.x.x for compatibility in old browsers.

In my case, I have bought a Bootstrap 4 theme and implement it on my WordPress site. However, adding jQuery v 3.2.1 as Boostrap 4 requirement, 4 of my plugins have conflict on it.

So I'm confuse how the developer of the theme do that?

Comment: Where are these conflicts happening, just in the frontend?

Answer (score 4):

I have just added bootstrap (css, js and popper.js) to my theme using CDN (preferred method) in the correct wordpress way.

It took me a while to figure out how to add integrity and crossorigin tags to the style and script imports, as seen on the example on https://getbootstrap.com/ under the '**BootstrapCDN**' section.

So here it goes. To add bootstrap to your theme, add this to the functions.php file inside your theme:

```
/**
 * Load bootstrap from CDN
 * https://getbootstrap.com/
 *
 * Added functions to add the integrity and crossorigin attributes to the style and script tags.
 */
function enqueue_load_bootstrap() {
    // Add bootstrap CSS
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );

    // Add popper js
    wp_register_script( 'popper-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js', ['jquery'], NULL, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper-js' );

    // Add bootstrap js
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', ['jquery'], NULL, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
}

// Add integrity and cross origin attributes to the bootstrap css.
function add_bootstrap_css_attributes( $html, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle === 'bootstrap-css' ) {
        return str_replace( '/>', 'integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />', $html );
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'add_bootstrap_css_attributes', 10, 2 );

// Add integrity and cross origin attributes to the bootstrap script.
function add_bootstrap_script_attributes( $html, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle === 'bootstrap-js' ) {
        return str_replace( '></script>', ' integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>', $html );
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_bootstrap_script_attributes', 10, 2);

// Add integrity and cross origin attributes to the popper script.
function add_popper_script_attributes( $html, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle === 'popper-js' ) {
        return str_replace( '></script>', ' integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>', $html );
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_popper_script_attributes', 10, 2);

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_load_bootstrap' );
```

Comment: Make sure to change the version...in case you are not using the same one

Answer (score 2):

You can dequeue the default jQuery of wordpress and then enqueue your bootstarp 4 jquery by using below code.

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "bootstarp_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function bootstarp_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

For more help see this link : [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script)

Comment: Is it possible to dequeue the jquery on themes php templates?

Comment: yes, You can dequeue the script by using handle name. Please write the above code in your current active theme functions.php file.

Comment: This does not solve the conflicts with plugins that rely on old jQuery versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load 2 versions of jQuery at the same time, you should make sure that the non-Wordpress version is **loaded first**. This is because the version that Wordpress ships runs in [compatibility mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), effectively restoring the `$` reference to the other version.

If you want to have a specific jQuery version for certain pages or templates only, you can use WordPress [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

Example: to enqueue jQuery 3+ for frontend calls only, you can:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) :
       wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
       wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'path-to-your-jquery-lib' );
    endif;
});
```

If you have conflicts with plugins that rely on old jQuery versions on specific pages, you can exclude those pages:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    if ( !is_admin() && !is_page( 'my-page' ) ) :
       wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
       wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'path-to-your-jquery-lib' );
    endif;
});
```

Comment: I have a global php which is called in all of the templates. I've added a cdn inside that global template for jQuery v 3.x. Is it okay if I didn't deregister the old version of the jQuery? Deregistering the old jQuery make more issues.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't deregister the jQuery v. 1.12.4 because v.3.x has a javascript error in Membership Plugin I'm using. And that membership plugin is used all over the pages.

Comment: Loading your scripts somewhere in your include files is not the way it should be done with WordPress, instead, use `wp_enqueue_script` like in the answers. Also, you didn't provide any console errors you might get in your original post, which might be helpful.